# XML - using xslt stylesheet, no output given

Tags: css, xml, xslt

So I'm currently using this xslt stylesheet to give my sitemap.xml some styling.
sitemap.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sitemap.xsl"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>https://lakupon.com/</loc>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://lakupon.com/tentang</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

sitemap.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Artist</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="urlset/url">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="loc" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="priority" /></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is this:
[sitemap.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbjr3.png)

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML, your elements have a default namespace "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9"

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

So in your XSL, you have to first declare the namespace, with a prefix (any prefix will do, I used "ns").

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
>
```

Finally in your XPath statements, you need to reference your nodes with the namespace prefix ("ns")

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns:urlset/ns:url">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ns:loc" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ns:priority" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Namespaces are ridiculous, don't add them to your own XML, but this is how to handle them when you have to.

Comment: Great.  Beware that the namespaces are required for sitemaps, so as bad as they are, you may be better off living with them, and addressing them in the XSL.